# sh: 2: ./ci.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected

Tags: bash

`ci.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ ERROR=$(npx cypress run configFile=reporter.config.json 2>&1 1>&$out); } {out}>&1
if [[ $ERROR == *"name_to_handle_at"* ]]; then # ERROR has the cypress error
    echo "expected ERROR detected: $ERROR"
    return 0
elif [ ! -z "$ERROR" ]; then # ERROR is not empty
    echo "ERROR detected: $ERROR"
    exit 1
fi
echo "no errors detected"
return 0 # row 11
```

Trying to start it with a `npm` script:

```
    "test": ". ./ci.sh && echo \"finished\"",
```

`npm run test` results in the error:

```
sh: 2: ./ci.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected
```

Don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I want the program to exit and not display "finished" if an error is detected from the command in the script file but I want it to continue if it finds a specific error or doesn't find any at all. When I use exit 0 in the script it never reaches "finished" (which makes sense since it's exiting the shell).

Bash is my main shell. NPM uses however `sh`.

Comment: Why are you `source`ing (`. ./ci.sh`) the command instead of just running it (`./ci.sh`)?

Comment: @AKX It's due to the `return` commands, I get the following error otherwise: `./ci.sh: line 11: return: can only 'return' from a function or sourced script`. :/

Comment: With these errors, would it not make more sense to completely replace this with a competently written script?

Comment: The calling code is apparently expected to set `out` to something useful;  I guess you will get a different error until you fix that too.

Comment: @Aaron I get this error if I do that: `./ci.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '${out}'`

Comment: @tripleee I used out just to capture stdout and store it temporarly, then display stderr to stdout, echo the saved original stdout then save the original stderr which was rerouted to stdout in the ERROR varaible. Check the contents of the ERROR variable and then set the return or exit accordingly. :/ I'm doing something wrong though!

Comment: @Aaron `{out}>&1` is legal *`bash`* syntax, but `npm` is likely running the script with `sh`.

Comment: @chepner I believe it is using `sh` due to the `sh` in the error messages.

Comment: agree that it looks like `sh` is in control here. But interesting that the `#!/bin/bash` she-bang line is being ignored. Prefix the call like `bash ./ci.sh`? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The command should be

```
 "test": "./ci.sh && echo \"finished\""
```

And you should replace the `return` statements with `exit`.

This will allow the script to run with its preferred interpreter bash instead of the system shell.